# Representing a single byte

Tags: java

A single `byte` takes up **four bytes** of space inside the Java virtual machine(*32 bit processor*).

Yes,we can use an array of byte which would occupy only the amount of space it actually needs. But I want to use a single byte **not** an array of bytes.

So,is there any **type** in `Java` to represent an **8 bit datum**.

Comment: *"A single byte takes up four bytes of space inside the Java virtual machine."* - [Citation needed]

Comment: @MichaelMyers hmm..right..am not sure on this..i guess it totally depends on the target processor..

Comment: Yes, the type to represent an 8 bit datum is called "byte". How to store it efficiently is up to the JVM, including the JIT. If your application requires tight control over data placement, you should probably not be writing it in Java.

Comment: I suppose you want to use bytes because of transmission control and throttling?

Comment: @Shark **no**..but i was curious to know it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **single** `byte` **can be** allocated more than a single byte of storage, for memory alignment reasons.

Do not worry about the target processor. An array of 10000 `byte`s **will be stored** in approximately 10000 bytes of space.

Comment: Read up on data structure alignment for background  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Java is a bit smarter about how it does alignment than C. Java will rearrange fields in order to take up less space. Nonetheless, the C examples are very instructive.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any type in Java to represent an 8 bit datum.

Yes, it is called `byte`.
How much a single `byte` actually needs only depends on the Java VM.

Answer (score 1):

It's up to the implementation (JVM) how to deal with the internal types. I guess any JVM on an 8bit machine uses 1 byte for the type `byte` - on 32bit or 64bit machines this might not always be the case, as you noticed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `byte` then Java will use the most efficient method to store it.  Might be 8 bits, might be 64 bits, but whatever it is it's for a good reason.  Don't fight the compiler, it knows better than you.

Answer (score 0):

A byte does represent an 8 bit datum. Why do you care how many bytes an implementation of a vm uses to store it?